# API Testing - getting value in squarebraces when using restassured for json resulting in assertion failure

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, get, rest-assured

I'm new to restassured. I'm trying with following API to fetch a json response and validate if the "capital" is "Oslo" or not.

But everytime assertion is failing since the value is fetched as [Oslo] instead of Oslo

Response JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Norway",
    "topLevelDomain": [
      ".no"
    ],
    "alpha2Code": "NO",
    "alpha3Code": "NOR",
    "callingCodes": [
      "47"
    ],
    "capital": "Oslo",
    "altSpellings": [
      "NO",
      "Norge",
      "Noreg",
      "Kingdom of Norway",
      "Kongeriket Norge",
      "Kongeriket Noreg"
    ],
    "relevance": "1.5",
    "region": "Europe",
    "subregion": "Northern Europe",
    "population": 5176998,
    "latlng": [
      62,
      10
    ],
    "demonym": "Norwegian",
    "area": 323802,
    "gini": 25.8,
    "timezones": [
      "UTC+01:00"
    ],
    "borders": [
      "FIN",
      "SWE",
      "RUS"
    ],
    "nativeName": "Norge",
    "numericCode": "578",
    "currencies": [
      "NOK"
    ],
    "languages": [
      "no",
      "nb",
      "nn"
    ],
    "translations": {
      "de": "Norwegen",
      "es": "Noruega",
      "fr": "Norvège",
      "ja": "ノルウェー",
      "it": "Norvegia"
    }
  }
]
```

My Code:

```
public class RestTest {

@Test
public void getRequestFindCapital() throws JsonException {

    given().when().get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/norway")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("capital", equalTo("Oslo"));
}
```

Assertion failure I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path capital doesn't match.
Expected: Oslo
Actual: [Oslo]


at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:471)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:643)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.content(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:265)
at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$content$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:248)
at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:268)
at RestTest.getRequestFindCapital(RestTest.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because if you look at the very top of your json, everything here is contained in an array. (Hence the square brackets).

While it is a little annoying it returns like this. An easy fix is to use something like the following:

```
body("capital", hasItem("Oslo"))
```

[Source where I got the direct code answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rest-assured/CXozJ2caMis)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I solved it using `contains` but `hasItem` also works.